# use of small functions

Tags: performance-tuning

I was wondering if it will slow down my code if I have a bunch of small functions like

```
isNewRound[currentMove_] := Return[Mod[currentMove, 4] == 0];
```

which are getting called very frequently? My program is already a bit slower than I want it to be. I'm not sure how mathematica is handling functions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `RepeatedTiming` shows that your function takes less than a microsecond to run so having small helper functions like this to make the rest of the code more readable is good practice.  One point I would make is to not use `Return` in your function definitions, just use `isNewRound[currentMove_] := Mod[currentMove, 4] == 0`

Comment: Functions like `RepeatedTiming`, `AbsoluteTiming`, and `EchoTiming` can be really helpful for locating bottlenecks.

Comment: If you are concerned about timing, try to use [`=`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) instead of [`:=`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) and define `isNewRound[currentMove_] = Divisible[currentMove, 4]`. See here: [immediate and delayed values](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/39-immediate-and-delayed-values.html).

Comment: Also, make sure that your small functions are [`Listable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) and try to call them on entire lists of values instead of calling them for every value separately.

Comment: Also, compile your function for specific input types (if known): `isNewRound = Compile[{{c, _Integer}}, Mod[c, 4] == 0, CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]`